# Why do I get unexpected index when looping a boost::hana::tuple

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, variant, boost-hana

Here is my code

```
using my_variant = std::variant<std::uint32_t, std::int32_t>;

auto my_types_map = hana::make_tuple(
  hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<std::uint32_t>, hana::integral_c<std::uint8_t, 0>),
  hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<std::int32_t>,  hana::integral_c<std::uint8_t, 1>) 
);

template <typename T>
void my_func(T& value)
{
  value = 32;
};

auto factory(std::uint8_t code, my_variant& value)
{
  std::function<void(my_variant&)> sub_fun;
  hana::for_each(my_types_map, [&](const auto& x)
    {
      if (code == hana::second(x))
      {
        using T = typename decltype(+hana::first(x))::type;
        sub_fun = [](my_variant& v){ my_func(std::get<T>(v)); };
      }
    });
  sub_fun(value);
}
```

When I call the first type all works fine, but when I call the second type I get an `unexpected index` exception at runtime:

```
my_variant v;
factory(0, v);    
assert(32 == std::get<std::uint32_t>(v)); // all fine
factory(1, v);    
assert(32 == std::get<std::int32_t>(v)); // unexpected index!
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: What do you mean, `unexpected index`. Do you mean you get a `bad_variant_access`?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing to do with Boost.Hana.

Here's a shorter reproduction:

```
std::variant<int, char> v;
std::get<char>(v) = 'X'; // this throws
```

`std::get` on a `variant` is type safe. You either get a `T&` to the `T` that is stored in the `variant`... or you get an exception. You cannot use `std::get` to change the underlying type of the variant. You can only do that by either assigning to the `variant` or invoking `emplace`. Nothing in your program does that, so when you try to access the type that it didn't have to begin with, you get an exception.

So you'll have to reconsider how this works.

And then just use [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html), since the hana::map you're using is just reconstructing your variant manually anyway:

```cpp
auto factory(std::uint8_t code, my_variant& value)
{
    mp_with_index<mp_size<my_variant>::size>(code, [&](auto I){
        value.emplace<I>(32);
    });
}
```

Comment: But the problem persist when I only call `my_variant v; factory(1, v);    
assert(32 == std::get<std::int32_t>(v));` which for me indicates that the problem does not lay with `variant` (also the exception is not a `bad_variant_access`).

Comment: @Reza It should be the exception - what exception are you getting (which should also be in the question).

Comment: @Reza Also, don't use Yoda conditionals... `assert(std::get<int>(v) == 32)`. There is absolutely no reason to write comparisons backwards.

Comment: It is a `std::bad_variant_access`. https://godbolt.org/z/QUQMHZ. The exception just has additional descriptive text associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that your setter expects that variant has already the expected type.

You should instead have:

```
auto factory(std::uint8_t code, my_variant& value)
{
  std::function<void(my_variant&)> sub_fun;
  hana::for_each(my_types_map, [&](const auto& x)
    {
      if (code == hana::second(x))
      {
        using T = typename decltype(+hana::first(x))::type;
        sub_fun = [](my_variant& v){ T t; my_func(t); v = t; };
      }
    });
  sub_fun(value);
}
```

Comment: But this solution involves one extra copy, which I'd like to avoid

Comment: By changing `my_func`, you might do `v = my_func<T>();`.